# Set iframe size on youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to tell the Youtube iframe API to set the iframes to be a certain size.  I used

[code]player.setPlaybackQuality('large');[/code]

to set quality but it did not set the correct size of the video (even though it says it does).  I am not able to specify exact numbers because the size is different for different videos.  For example some videos are (560x315, 640x360, etc...)  while other videos can have other sizes.  How do I set a category of sizes?

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS Style on the IFRAME and set your own width and height on the IFRAME.

Comment: I can not set a specific number.  I have to set a general size category.

Comment: I have same issue. Ryu did you get solution?